# Kibana (https) can't access ElasticSearch (http) in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, azure, https, elasticsearch, kibana

I have an Azure website running Kibana with an https endpoint. I also have an ElasticSearch cluster running in an Azure cloud service with a load balanced endpoint (http).

When I access Kibana's https URL from Chrome, everything works fine. However, when I access it with Internet Explorer 11 I get an "Access Denied" error in app.js and an error is displayed in Kibana saying

*"Could not contact Elasticsearch at `http://myCloudServiceUrl:9200`. Please ensure that Elasticsearch is reachable from your system. "*

I'd imagine this is due to a security configuration in IE, and that the problem is caused because both URLs are in different domains, or mixed http/https, or the 9200 port... But can't pinpoint or fix it.

Could you help me out making Kibana work for IE 11 in this scenario?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I know this is off topic but any tips on setting up kibana on Azure Website? I can't find any literature on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is going from https to http. IE doesn't like it.

Stay http on both or https on both. Certificate does not matter. Also ES should be privately
Accessible and Kibana should also be private.
For ease of configuration, use http for both

DO NOT have ES publicly accessible. That's the equivalent of making your Wordpress MySQL database accessible to the world.
ES is a REST accessible DB which means that anyone can delete all of your data with access to the endpoint.

Comment: I am using IP filtering for ES to limit it's access from the outside world (I need them accessible from my on-premise network). However, I was planning to use ADFS authentication for Kibana, but that requires using https. This was causing the problem. I could make them both run under http, and use IP filtering for Kibana as well; or make ES run under https, and use ADFS with Kibana. However adding https to ES doesn't seem to be very straightforward...

Do you think this would make sense?

Comment: We have a virtual private network connected to our office network to limit access to internal resources. If you can manage it, https on both is preferable, but http is easier

Comment: @dcinzona: "DO NOT have ES publicly accessible." Can you please explain this or provide a link to read further on it?? I am new to the ELK stack and think you are suggesting an important security concern, so if you could elaborate please.

Comment: It's a little bit of common sense.  ES (version < 1.4 ) didn't have any security implementations out of the box, and because it uses full REST implementation, without the additional security measures, ANYONE that has access to the REST API endpoints can access (modify) your data.